# Problems using dompdf and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I have started experimenting with codeigniter and pdfs. I'm using the latest version of both. For some reason, i'm getting this error when trying to render the pdfs:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\Users\Manfred\Dropbox\Web\Alodu\application\helpers\dompdf/include/ci_exceptions.cls.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Manfred\Dropbox\Web\Alodu\application\helpers\dompdf\dompdf_config.inc.php on line 208

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Manfred\Dropbox\Web\Alodu\application\helpers\dompdf/include/ci_exceptions.cls.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\Manfred\Dropbox\Web\Alodu\application\helpers\dompdf\dompdf_config.inc.php on line 208
```

Code used is:

```
function pdf()
    {
         $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
         // page info here, db calls, etc.     

         /*
         $data=array(
         "$title"=>"Hello!",
         "$test_questions"=>"1,2,3,4",
         );
         */

        $data['test_questions']= "hello";


         $html = $this->load->view('pdf/test_ibdp', $data, true);

         $filename="Test".$data['test_questions'];

         pdf_create($html, $filename);
         write_file('name', $data);

    }
```

And the helper:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
function pdf_create($html, $filename, $stream=TRUE) 
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->set_paper("a4", "portrait" );
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename . ".pdf");
}
?>
```

and the view (pure HTML)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HelloAgain</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions? I'm not that experienced in PHP and i'm quite confused. I just re-downloaded the library, i've tried keeping it really simple by stripping away extras in my code. Nothing seems to work. any help would be great :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a class autoloader issue. Which version of DOMPDF do you use? I think dompdf 0.5 had a problem when integrated inside a framework like CI.
The 0.6 version doesn't have this probleme anymore, and if the problem persists, write

```
define("DOMPDF_AUTOLOAD_PREPEND", true)
```

in `dompdf_config.custom.inc.php`.

Comment: Seems fixed in DOMPDF 0.6.0 beta 3 . Thanks Fabien for a great software.

Answer (score 0):

Correct the dompdf file path. Also remove this line of code:

```
write_file('name', $data);
```

The following line is enough:

```
pdf_create($html, $filename);
```

Comment: Everything Working! What i did was that I actually replaced it with the dompdf 6.0 beta instead of the 5.2 that was, despite being a clean copy of the website, not working for some strange reason. I thought something was fishy when it I couldn't find the missing file. Thanks a lot for the help nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying the path below is not correct. Recheck the path

```
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Path to the file is incorrect.

C:\Users\Manfred\Dropbox\Web\Alodu\application\helpers\dompdf`/`include`/`ci_exceptions.cls.php

You can use [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php).